# Storing custom .Net objects in Azure Redis Cache with StackExchange.Redis

Tags: c#, linq, azure, stackexchange.redis

We're implementing [StackExchange.Redis](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis) for storing all information regarding three e-commerce sites (aproximately 18,500 products). The information is stored in a SQL Server database, mapped to custom objects and then added in an Azure Redis Cache using this key naming convention:

```
urn:products:{0}:{1}
```

(where 0 is the store identifier and 1 is the product identifier). I read [Where are KEYS, SCAN, FLUSHDB etc?](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/Docs/KeysScan.md) and was able to get keys matching the `urn:products:{0}` by pattern. The issue that we´re facing is that our project involves a lot of `GetAllProducts List < Products >`, `GetAllCategories List < Categories >` and then used by LINQ functions.

Based on this:

- I tried storing all products (list of custom objects) in one key (`urn:products:all`), but that approach generated timeouts in Azure Redis Cache. Is this method the suggested one? Or is it preferable to store each product in separate keys?
- I don't think that is correct to loop each of the keys to get each value. Is it possible to get a collection of keys/values by pattern?
- I also read HASHES, however I don't think that they help in our requirement.

Comment: You can't @ people in questions.

Comment: When you ask is it ok That sounds like opinion based answers will be given so not suitable for SO

Comment: Removed @ in question (didn´t know that). Changed first question to avoid opinion based answers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering your approach to call tons of records at once. I recommend to slice them no more than a thousand records.

Redis only has very limited feature, so your requirement may not be fulfilled. Redis is good for cache or simple key-value getter and setter. For that, you may consider other memory-based databases such as MongoDB.

In your case, Redis **Set** is the best approach to combine or substract with given conditions, or **Hash** is for property-based object storing. Whatever approach you choose, you will use two or more datatypes because Redis datatypes are not so versatile.

RedisCookbook describes good example.

- http://www.rediscookbook.org/implement_tags_and_search_them.html
- http://www.rediscookbook.org/introduction_to_storing_objects.html